# How to sendkeys to a <p> tag through C# and Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

i want to sendkeys "description" within a textarea. I have tried all the possible ways but does not work.

HTML of the element :

```html
<div class="ta-scroll-window ng-scope ta-text ta-editor form-control" ng-hide="showHtml">
  <div class="popover fade bottom" style="max-width: none; width: 305px;">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="popover-content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="ta-resizer-handle-overlay">
    <div class="ta-resizer-handle-background"></div>
    <div class="ta-resizer-handle-corner ta-resizer-handle-corner-tl"></div>
    <div class="ta-resizer-handle-corner ta-resizer-handle-corner-tr"></div>
    <div class="ta-resizer-handle-corner ta-resizer-handle-corner-bl"></div>
    <div class="ta-resizer-handle-corner ta-resizer-handle-corner-br"></div>
    <div class="ta-resizer-handle-info"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="taTextElement737852736512107" contenteditable="true" ta-bind="ta-bind" ng-model="html" ta-keep-styles="true" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ta-bind ng-empty ng-touched" an-form-object-name="Açıklama" name="Açıklama">
    <p>
      <br>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Code trial :

```
Dim action2 = New Actions(driver)
Dim cekbul2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*@id=""taHtmlElement737852736512107""]"))
cekbul2.SendKeys("Açıklama")
Console.Write("textarea send description")
```

or

```
 Dim cekbul2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//textarea[@class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ta-bind ta-html ta-editor form-control ng-empty ng-hide' and @id='taHtmlElement737852736512107']"))
```

The error is :

```
"no such element: Unable to locate element does not work"  give error
```

Comment: `does not work` is very vague. errors? is an element found or not? is it found but not entering text?

Comment: "no such element: Unable to locate element:"  error give

Comment: I don't see any `<textarea>` tag within the HTML you have provided

Comment: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*@id="taHtmlElement737852736512107"] because of the following error: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*@id="taHtmlElement737852736512107"]' is not a valid XPath expression.  this error give

Comment: are you sure that is what the xpath is (or could be) for the element you want

Comment: See below answer -  your xPath has a syntax error in it - it is missing a starting square bracket.

Comment: no such element: Unable to locate element  does not work

Answer (score 0):

Your html does not have a text area input field inside it.
When you use an xPath that says 
'//textarea'  this means that you are looking for an element that has tags of `<textarea> </textarea>`

It looks like your html is actually div's that are styled up to look like text areas.
That is why your second attempt will never work - because you are looking for a textarea where none exists.

Typically, in the situation where a div is styled up to work like a text area or textbox, you will find that the div has a backing input behind it.
These must be located between the 
`<form> and </form>` tags in the html - otherwise the server would never be able to receive the data. (Html 5 provides new ways of working with this - but that is another story)
Can you examine your full html, and see if you can find the actual text area objects or the input type objects that end up containing the text content.
Type some dummy text, and use an html inspector tool within chrome or firefox to look for your dummy text.

If however, the post is completed by javascript - you may find that the javascript does not use inputs or text areas for containing the text and instead posts it external to any form elements. This is common with richtext emulators such as forum post pages.

If that is the case- you may need to experiment and find the appropriate html element that you need to send keys to in order for the content to work.
Also - could you try

```
Dim cekbul2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='taHtmlElement737852736512107']"))
```

I couldnt help but notice it had an xPath syntax error - you had no starting [ square bracket ] - also, in programming it is sometimes considered lazy a bad practice to wildcard / work with dynamics. I recommend always using the tag type for your xpaths, as opposed to '//*'

Worse case scenario, I would say that you could probably get around this by using Javascript execution. Eg: Directly setting the text, instead of 'sending the key strokes'.
However, this does not emulate human behavior - but it may be a necessary evil depending on your situation.

Comment: i understand. program "no such element: Unable to locate element: " this error give. a different site

Answer (score 0):

To send text to the `<p>` tag you have to use the [**`ExecuteScript()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IJavaScriptExecutor_ExecuteScript.htm) method from [**`IJavaScriptExecutor`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_IJavaScriptExecutor.htm) Interface and you can use the following code block :

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML="Hasan Sarıkaya";");
```

Comment: wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@class='ng-pristine ng-valid ta-bind ng-empty ng-touched' and starts-with(@id,'taTextElement')]"))).SendKeys("Açiklama")  --->    Timed out after 1 seconds  error

Comment: @HasanSarıkaya Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

I want to highlight some points here

***Most probably your locator which you are using is not correct.***

*There are three way which I know to enter text using selenium*

1)**Use driver.findElement(yourLoator).sendKeys("Stringvalue");**

2)***You can use action class to send keys***

3)**You can use javascript executor to change innerHtml code**

*Personally ill not prefer the third solution, because we are testers I believe changing dom attribute is a good practice*

Hope this will give you some help. please Let me know in case any query.